# How and why use curly braces: return $this->{$this->action}();

Tags: php, function, class, methods

so in first part i made 2 object, instantiate two classes (one we generate from createController function)

```
$loader = new Loader(); 
$controller = $loader->createController(); 
$controller->executeAction();
```

and the method `executeAction` code:

```
public function executeAction() {
    return $this->{$this->action}();
}
```

my question is taking this line of code: `$this->{$this->action}()` how this method is called and why use curly braces; Is trying to execute the `action();` function of extended class maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->{$this->action}();
```

means that the method that should be called comes from the property `$this->action`.

```
$this->action = 'func1';
$this->{$this->action}();
```

is equivalent to:

```
$this->func1();
```

See the PHP documentation of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for more examples of this. The braces are needed because `$this->$this->action()` would normally be treated as `($this->$this)->action()`.

Comment: yes work fine in bout ways, but is the firs time when i saw this type of implementation using Accolades and (), i was interested in this part`{}();`

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by _accolades_. That word means awards, it doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: `{}` = curly braces, `()` = parentheses, `[]` = square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the `$this->action` in another local variable and then, call it:

```
$action = $this->action;
$this->$action();
```

Comment: Yep! is the same, but i don't know how the method is called

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain a little bit more about "how the method is called"?

Comment: in this code Accolades are used before parentesis `{}();` not like `functions` are made `(){}` is more like Javascript `({})()`. And i don't know how to name it looking at the parentesis, is more like a function something

Comment: Yes, curly braces i mean by word: Accolades,